# how to use phpmailer instead of tmail in agile toolkit?

Tags: atk4

How can we use PHPMailer instead of Tmail in agile toolkit?

something like this:

```
     $phpmailer=$this->add("phpmailer");
     $phpmailer->functions...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add atk4-addons
2. add phpmailer lib

   git submodule add https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.git .
3. setup mail to use PHPMailer class

   $mail = $this->add("TMail");
   $mail->addTransport("PHPMailer");
4. update your `config.php`, e.g.

   $config["tmail"]["from"] = "info@bla.com";
   $config["tmail"]["smtp"]["host"] = "ip";
   $config["tmail"]["smtp"]["port"] = "25";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["reply_to"] = "info@bla.com";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["reply_to_name"]  = "bla";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["from"] = "info@bla.com";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["from_name"] = "bla";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["bcc"] = "support@bla.com";
   $config["tmail"]["phpmailer"]["bcc_name"] = "bla";

Comment: set display_errors to "on", error_reporting = E_ALL in your config.php. blank page means that you have php error.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other 3rd part library.

```
require 'path/to/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

You can use

```
$this->api->pm->base_directory
```

to start path from base directory of project.

```
require $this->api->pm->base_directory.'path/to/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/PageManager.php#L73

Comment: Is this a proper way for agile toolkit?

Comment: Yes. I don't like this way because of "include", but sometime there is no other way to use 3'rd part classes and libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can actually configure TMail to use PHPMailer for delivering your messages:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/blob/master/misc/lib/TMail/Transport/PHPMailer.php